# Sort by Section of Sum Field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau Desktop, so I'm guessing what I want to do is simple, but I don't know how to do it.

Basically, I have basketball data that gives me players total points scored over several seasons with different NBA teams.  I'm trying to sort that data by team, based on the amount that each player scored for each specific team.

Right now, I have the data sorted by team, player, and the total number of points scored.  The problem is - I don't actually want the total sum.  (E.g. right now Shaq is listed first under the Celtics because he has the most career points out of anyone who played for the Celtics, but not for the Celtics themselves.)

Can someone tell me how I would go about sorting by sum points by team?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually such a common issue that Tableau references a solution in their official training material. If my understanding of your requirement is correct, the following should solve the problem.
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/finding-top-n-within-category